# Robot Framework ASCII Code Encoding - error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' ... ordinal not in range(128)"

Tags: python, robotframework

I am looking for a way to solve:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Currently my code is:

```
    coding: utf-8
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is a simple test with Robot Framework
Suite Setup     Connect To Database    pymysql    ${DBName}    ${DBUser}    ${DBPass}    ${DBHost}    ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown  Disconnect From Database
Library         Selenium2Library
Library         DatabaseLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem
Library         String

*** Variables ***
${DBHost}         localhost
${DBName}         robottest
${DBPass}         sahill
${DBPort}         3306
${DBUser}         sahill

*** Test Cases ***
Open Browser To Start Roboting
    [Documentation]  Sarting robot
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser  http://movieplus.cc/a-z-movies/    firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
    WAIT UNTIL PAGE CONTAINS    have any legal issues please contact appropriate media file owners / hosters.

    Click Element   xpath=//div[@class='wrapper']//div[@class='thumbs']//div[@class='wrap']//div[1]//a
    WAIT UNTIL PAGE CONTAINS    have any legal issues please contact appropriate media file owners / hosters.
    ${count} =  Get Matching Xpath Count     xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//ul[@class='list']//li
    ${title} =  get text    xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//h2[@class='title']//span[@class='color']
    ${cate} =   get text    xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//ul[@class='list']
    ${director} =   get text    xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//div[1]//span[@class='desc']
    ${cast} =   get text    xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//div[2]//span[@class='desc']
    ${content} =    get text    xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//div[3]//span[@class='description']//p
    ${image_link} =     Get element attribute    xpath=//div[@class='content']//div[@class='wrap_img']//img@src
    Execute SQL String      INSERT INTO test VALUES('${title}', '${cate}', '${director}', '${cast}','${content}', '${image_link}', 'link');
    Go Back
```

In the `${content}` variable, this content is stored:

> A young woman wakes up in the basement of a man who claims he saved her life after pulling her from her overturned car which violently crashed along the highway. The man states that the world above them is no longer safe and is now a danger zone that threatens the rest of humanity. With no knowledge of what actually lies above and trust running thin between them, the woman questions **what’s true and what’s not**. Is the man a delusional psychotic that has a more sinister agenda for her? Or is it really hell on earth above ground like he swears?

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3 ?

Comment: Python 2, with python 3 robot framework not work

Comment: this is website [link](http://movieplus.cc/a-z-movies/) and this is the code `${content} =    get text    xpath=//div[@class='wrap_content']//div[3]//span[@class='description']//p` and when i run robot framework this error is shown `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 590: ordinal not in range(256)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using python 2, so, you issue is that you have not defined a proper encoding at the start of your file.

```
# coding: utf-8
```

You have the choice to:

- Put the encoding header at the top of your file
- or:

  ```
  Use an ascii character for "’", like "'"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, basically i make a system in which i get content using robot framework get text keyword from a website,  in that case am not able to change " ' "

Comment: @Sahill This is not what I see in your code, could you update it to provide a similar to real world example ?

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the SQL string, you may Encode the content, like in:

```
${content} =    Encode String To Bytes    ${content}    ASCII    errors=replace
```

In this case the result is: `... the woman questions what?s true and what?s not. Is the ...`

If you ignore the errors:

```
${content} =    Encode String To Bytes    ${content}    ASCII    errors=ignore
```

The result will be: `... the woman questions whats true and whats not. Is the ...`

(which will be more comprehensible)